# Laravel showing blank page

Tags: laravel, nginx

I just setup a Laravel 5 framework in my server by typing in terminal

`laravel new blog` (in "/var/www/html/" folder),

then changed the default config of Nginx so the root pointing to : `root /var/www/html/blog/public;`

of-course all the files are in place however I currently just see a blank page showing up ! I tried to put a html & PHP file in public folder and it all works fine. but not Laravel default index file. what am I missing here ?

Comment: check error log, check http status code

Comment: @ash Check permission on app/storage directory

Answer (score -1):

For adding pages in Laravel you do not simply put files in `/public`. Please have a look at the [official Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views) page if you want to create new views.

Laravel uses the MVC principle. So you need to have at least a view (the part which is displayed) and a controller which handles the view. To add a new [Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers), please change to the project root `cd /var/www/html/blog` and type in `php artisan controller:make AwesomeController` which creates the controller in `app/Http/Controllers/AwesomeController.php`.

In this Controller you can simply return a view by adding `return view('myview')` to the `index()` Method for example. (The view has to exist at `resources/views/myview.blade.php` of course)

In the last step you need to tell Laravel how to call your controller. Please modify the `routes.php` file at `app/Http/routes.php` and add `Route::get('foo', 'AwesomeController');`. Now you need to tell composer that some of your controllers may have changed and composer needs to refresh the cache. Type in `composer dump-autoload` and start the development server `php artisan serve`.

By calling `http://localhost:8000/foo` (by default) you should see your View. Have a nice day!